# Pythonic String Manipulation

Tags: python, string, dictionary

How can I do the following in a more efficient python friendly way?

```
first_team= re.sub("Northern", "N", first_team)
first_team=re.sub("Western", "W", first_team)
first_team=re.sub("Southern", "S", first_team)
first_team=re.sub("Eastern", "E", first_team)
```

Answer (score 4):

Use a for-loop:

```
for direction in ('Northern', 'Western', 'Southern', 'Eastern'):
    first_team = first_team.replace(direction, direction[0])
```

There's no need to use `re.sub` here for dealing with such simple replacement :), [`str.replace`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.replace) is perfectly fine.

Comment: Your code is fine for this specific example. If OP really wants just this, good. But for a general replacement, one would need to specify a mapping as other poster proposed.

Answer (score 3):

I would use `.replace` and do:

```
opts = [ ("Northern", "N"), ("Western", "W"), ("Southern", "S"), ("Eastern", "E") ]

for opt in opts:
    first_team = first_team.replace(opt[0], opt[1])
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `re.sub()`s can be rewritten into a one-liner using `lambda` as a second argument:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "Northern Western Southern Eastern" 
>>> re.sub("(Northern|Western|Southern|Eastern)", lambda x: x.group(1)[0] , s)
'N W S E'
```

Note that the replacement is too simple for doing it via regex.

But, what if, for example, you want to replace strings like `north`, `North` too:

```
>>> s = "Northern North north Western Southern Eastern" 
>>> re.sub("([Nn]orth(ern)?|[Ww]est(ern)?|[Ss]outh(ern)?|[Ee]ast(ern)?)", lambda x: x.group(1)[0].upper(), s)
'N N N W S E'
```

That's there you may need to use `re.sub`.

---

Also, you may use `replace()` with a [reduce()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reduce):

```
>>> opts = {"Northern": "N", "Western": "W", "Southern": "S", "Eastern": "E"}
>>> reduce(lambda k, v: k.replace(*v), opts.iteritems(), s)
'N W S E'
```

This is basically the same as applying `replace()` in a for loop but written in a functional programming style.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to show you my own solution. At the first view, it might be complicated, but after defining the "basics", application is really simple

First, I define a mapping as a list of tuples:

```
our_mapping = [("Northern", "N"),
           ("Western", "W"),
           ("Southern", "S"),
           ("Eastern", "E")]
```

Now comes the beef: I define a factory function that recursively creates an All-In-One replacement function:

```
def replacer_factory(mapping):
    if len(mapping) < 1:
        return lambda x: x
    original, replacement = mapping[0]
    return lambda x: replacer_factory(mapping[1:])(x.replace(original, replacement))
```

Now I can create a replacement function with my mapping:

```
our_replacer = replacer_factory(our_mapping)
```

And then application is really easy:

```
>>> in_ = "Northern Western Southern Eastern"
>>> out_ = our_replacer(in_)
>>> print in_
Northern Western Southern Eastern
>>> print out_
N W S E
```

I really like that we don't need any parameters to call `our_replacer`, all the mapping-logic has been hidden inside of it. One can now easily define arbitrary replacers and use them.

Here the code as a whole:

```
our_mapping = [("Northern", "N"),
           ("Western", "W"),
           ("Southern", "S"),
           ("Eastern", "E")]

def replacer_factory(mapping):
    if len(mapping) < 1:
        return lambda x: x
    original, replacement = mapping[0]
    return lambda x: replacer_factory(mapping[1:])(x.replace(original, replacement))

our_replacer = replacer_factory(our_mapping)

in_ = "Northern Western Southern Eastern"
out_ = our_replacer(in_)

print in_
print out_
```

I agree that this can be considered "advanced" - so if you are a newbie and "just want it to work", stick to jabaldonedos answer.

Comment: Doing this recursively is just un-necessary, inefficient and overly complicated :(